# Where to use uvm_blocking_put_port and uvm_analysis_port?

Tags: uvm

What is the difference between port and analysis port ?
Where to use uvm_blocking_put_port and where to use uvm_analysis_port ?
What is advantage of uvm_analysis_port over uvm_blocking_put_port ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port connection is used to connect two independent blocks(components).
Both uvm_blocking_put_port and uvm_analysis_port used to transfer data from producer to consumer.

(1) uvm_blocking_put_port:
Used for data transfer from a single producer to a single consumer.

(2) uvm_analysis_port:
Used for data transfer from a single producer to a single consumer or multiple   consumers.

Advantage for this analysis port is that a user can transfer data from a single producer to multiple consumers that is not archived with help of uvm_blocking_put_port.

This thing is also explained in the figure.

Here I provide sample code to get more clarity for uvm_blocking_put_port and  uvm_analysis_port.

[This image explain use of uvm_blocking_put_port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIVfM.png)

Remember:  Port connection is used to connect two or more independent component.

(1) uvm_blocking_put_port EXAMPLE.

```
class transaction extends uvm_sequence_item;
  `uvm_object_utils(transaction);
  rand int unsigned a;
  rand int unsigned b;

  function new(string name ="");
    super.new(name);
  endfunction

endclass


class producer extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(producer);
  transaction tr_inst;
  uvm_blocking_put_port #(transaction) produce_to_consumer_p;

  function new(string name ="",uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name,parent);
    produce_to_consumer_p = new("produce_to_consumer_p",this);
    tr_inst = new("tr_inst");
  endfunction


  task run_phase(uvm_phase phase) ;
    super.run_phase(phase);
    phase.raise_objection(this);
    //tr_inst.randomize();
    `uvm_info(get_full_name(),"Write the data from PRODUCER",UVM_LOW)
    tr_inst.a = 10; tr_inst.b = 20;
    produce_to_consumer_p.put(tr_inst);
    phase.drop_objection(this);
  endtask

endclass

class consumer extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(consumer);
  uvm_blocking_put_imp#(transaction,consumer) put_imp;  
  //transaction tr_inst;

  function new(string name ="",uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name,parent);
    put_imp = new("put_imp",this); 
  endfunction

  function void put(transaction tr_inst);
    `uvm_info(get_full_name(),"Got the data in CONSUMER",UVM_LOW);
    `uvm_info(get_full_name(),$sformatf("the value of a %0d and b is %0d",tr_inst.a,tr_inst.b),UVM_LOW);
  endfunction

endclass

class env extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(env);

  producer p_inst;
  consumer c_inst;

  function new(string name="",uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name,parent);
    p_inst = new("p_inst",this);
    c_inst = new("c_inst",this);
  endfunction

  function void connect();
    p_inst.produce_to_consumer_p.connect(c_inst.put_imp);
  endfunction

endclass

module main();

  env env_inst;

  initial 
  begin
    env_inst = new("env_inst",null);
    run_test();
  end

endmodule
```

[This image gives explanation of uvm_analysis_port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3lcM.png)
(2) uvm_analysis_port EXAMPLE

```
class transaction extends uvm_sequence_item;
  `uvm_object_utils(transaction);
  rand int unsigned a;
  rand int unsigned b;

  function new(string name ="");
    super.new(name);
  endfunction

endclass


class producer extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(producer);
  transaction tr_inst;
  uvm_analysis_port #(transaction) produce_to_consumer_p;

  function new(string name ="",uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name,parent);
    produce_to_consumer_p = new("produce_to_consumer_p",this);
    tr_inst = new("tr_inst");
  endfunction


  task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.run_phase(phase);
    phase.raise_objection(this);
//    tr_inst.randomize();
    `uvm_info(get_full_name(),"Write the data from PRODUCER",UVM_LOW);
    tr_inst.a = 10; tr_inst.b = 20;
    produce_to_consumer_p.write(tr_inst);
    phase.drop_objection(this);
  endtask

endclass

class consumer_1 extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(consumer_1);
  uvm_analysis_imp#(transaction,consumer_1) write_imp_1;  

  function new(string name ="",uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name,parent);
    write_imp_1 = new("write_imp_1",this); 
  endfunction

  function void write(transaction tr_inst);
    `uvm_info(get_full_name(),"Got the data in CONSUMER_1",UVM_LOW);
    `uvm_info(get_full_name(),$sformatf("The value of a = %0d and b = %0d",tr_inst.a,tr_inst.b),UVM_LOW);
  endfunction

endclass

class consumer_2 extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(consumer_2);
  uvm_analysis_imp#(transaction,consumer_2) write_imp_2;  

  function new(string name ="",uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name,parent);
    write_imp_2 = new("write_imp_2",this); 
  endfunction

  function void write(transaction tr_inst);
    `uvm_info(get_full_name(),"Got the data in CONSUMER_2",UVM_LOW);
    `uvm_info(get_full_name(),$sformatf("The value of a = %0d and b = %0d",tr_inst.a,tr_inst.b),UVM_LOW);
  endfunction

endclass

class consumer_3 extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(consumer_3);
  uvm_analysis_imp#(transaction,consumer_3) write_imp_3;  

  function new(string name ="",uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name,parent);
    write_imp_3 = new("write_imp_3",this); 
  endfunction

  function void write(transaction tr_inst);
    `uvm_info(get_full_name(),"Got the data in CONSUMER_3",UVM_LOW);
    `uvm_info(get_full_name(),$sformatf("The value of a = %0d and b = %0d",tr_inst.a,tr_inst.b),UVM_LOW);
  endfunction

endclass

class env extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(env);

  producer p_inst;
  consumer_1 c_inst_1;
  consumer_2 c_inst_2;
  consumer_3 c_inst_3;

  function new(string name="",uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name,parent);
    p_inst = new("p_inst",this);
    c_inst_1 = new("c_inst_1",this);
    c_inst_2 = new("c_inst_2",this);
    c_inst_3 = new("c_inst_3",this);
  endfunction

  function void connect();
    p_inst.produce_to_consumer_p.connect(c_inst_1.write_imp_1);
    p_inst.produce_to_consumer_p.connect(c_inst_2.write_imp_2);
    p_inst.produce_to_consumer_p.connect(c_inst_3.write_imp_3);
  endfunction

endclass

module main();

  env env_inst;
  initial 
  begin
    env_inst = new("env_inst",null);
    run_test();
  end

endmodule
```